# How big can my auth.log file get

Tags: 18.04, server, wireless, security

I have an ssh server running with ubuntu 18.04.
It is online for about a week now.

Yesterday I found out that ssh servers get attacked every single minute :(

Now i've enabled fail2ban and I have a very strong root and a very strong user password.

But of course, I still get attacked.

**How big can the auth.log file get? Is there something like a limit, or will it get so big that my server gets slower?**
Thanks for your help and stay heathy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Ubuntu system *rotates* logs to prevent them from growing to enormous size with ancient data.

Logfiles get rotated by the `logrotate` service. Default is weekly, and that is configurable in /etc/logrotate/ . Older logs are compressed, then eventually deleted.

- See `man logrotate` and `man logrotate.conf`

Here's an example of what rotated logs look like:

```
$ ls -lh /var/log | grep auth
-rw-r-----  1 syslog    adm      46K Jul  3 07:30 auth.log
-rw-r-----  1 syslog    adm     108K Jun 30 09:32 auth.log.1
-rw-r-----  1 syslog    adm     5.5K Jun 21 15:01 auth.log.2.gz
-rw-r-----  1 syslog    adm     6.3K Jun 14 07:27 auth.log.3.gz
-rw-r-----  1 syslog    adm     7.6K Jun  7 08:58 auth.log.4.gz
```